# The number of people cannot be initialized in the word chain game

Tags: javascript, html

This is a word chain game I made.
When the game is over, the text is initialized.
Other texts are initialized fine, but the text in span.number-of-people is not.
In the console window console.log(numberOfPeople.textContent); It looks like it has been initialized.
But why is the number not erased from the screen?

```js
const numberOfPeople = document.querySelector(".number-of-people");
const previousWord = document.querySelector(".previous-word");
const inputWord = document.querySelector("#input-word");
const submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-button");

let number = parseInt(prompt("How many people are participating in the game?"));
let word;

const gameStart = () => {
    if(number) {
        numberOfPeople.textContent = number;
    } else {
        number = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number."));
        gameStart();
    }
}

gameStart();

const onClickSubmitButton = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    word = inputWord.value;
    if (inputWord.value.length < 3) {
        alert("Please enter 3 or more characters and less than 10 characters.")
    } else if ((previousWord.textContent === "") || (previousWord.textContent[previousWord.textContent.length - 1] === word[0])) {
        previousWord.textContent = word;
        inputWord.value = "";
        inputWord.focus();
    } else {
        alert("GAME_OVER");
        inputWord.value = "";
        previousWord.textContent = "";
        console.log(numberOfPeople.textContent); // The result of this code is number of people.
        numberOfPeople.textContent = ""; // This code is not working.
        console.log(numberOfPeople.textContent); // The result of this code is "".
        gameStart();
        return;
    }
}

submitButton.addEventListener("click", onClickSubmitButton);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>word-chain game</title>
    <script src="js/word-chain_game.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="word-chain__wrapper">
        <h4>number-of-people : <span class="number-of-people"></span></h4>
        <h4>previous-word : <span class="previous-word"></span></h4>
        <form>
            <label for="input-word">enter a word</label>
            <input name="input-word" id="input-word" type="text" required minlength="3" maxlength="10" placeholder="Please enter a word.">
            <input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="input"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working.  But then you're calling `gameStart()`.  Which does this:

```
if(number) {
    numberOfPeople.textContent = number;
}
```

So the code is successfully clearing the text in that element and then *immediately* putting it back again.

You probably also meant to reset the `number` variable when ending the game:

```
numberOfPeople.textContent = "";
number = null;
```

Keep in mind of course that this will likely lead you to start re-thinking some UX.  Because while this "works", the use of `prompt()` will block the UI from updating, and then immediately after `promt()` the new value is again used.  So the code still never *visually* empties that field.